# International characters not showing correctly in Java PDF export

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I am trying to export chinese/japanese characters AND polish characters to a pdf. But only one of both works, not both, and I don't understand why. 
Here is the program:

```
public class Japanese {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuffer writer = new StringBuffer();
    writer.append("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1?DTD/transitional.dtd\">\n" + 
            "<html>\n" + 
            "<head>\n" + 
            "<META http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />\n" + 
            "<title>some title.</title>\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "<style type=\"text/css\">\n" + 
            "     .myDiv\n" + 
            "   {\n" + 
            "         font-family: \"Noto Sans CJK TC Regular\", Sans-Serif;\n" +
            "     }\n" + 
            "</style>\n" + 
            "</head>\n" + 
            "<body> <div class=\"myDiv\">" + 
            "Chinese: 百威英博雪津(三明)啤酒有限公司 <br />" + 
            "Japanese: 日本にほんでは、近頃ちかごろ多おおくの人ひとが保育園ほいくえん問題もんだいについて話はなしている。 <br />" +  
            "Polish: ąćęł <br />" +
            "German: TüööäE_3STß <br />" +
            "Hello World: 你好，世界 <br />" + 
            "\n" + 
            "    <br />\n" + 
            "\n" + 
            "END TEXT\n</div>" + 
            "<br />\n" + 
            "<br />\n" + 
            "</body></html>");
    String  pdfContent = writer.toString();

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();           

    ITextFontResolver resolver = renderer.getFontResolver();

    resolver.addFont("lib/NotoSans-Regular.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    resolver.addFont("lib/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(pdfContent);
    renderer.layout();
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.pdf");
    renderer.createPDF(os);

    System.out.println("Finished");
}
```

The program above creates a pdf with correct japanese/chinese characters. For this, I leave this line as it is:

```
" font-family: \"Noto Sans CJK TC Regular\", Sans-Serif;\n" +
```

But the polish characters are not shown, only the japanese/chinese. If I change the line above to:

```
" font-family: \"Noto Sans\", Sans-Serif;\n" +
```

then the chinese/japanese are not shown, only the polish.

I would expect that with this line, both would be shown correctly:

```
" font-family: \"Noto Sans\", \"Noto Sans CJK TC Regular\", Sans-Serif;\n" +
```

But only the polish characters are shown correctly. Here: https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/guidelines/ it is stated, that this is the correct way to achieve this:

```
font-family: "Noto Sans", "Noto Sans CJK JP", sans-serif;
```

So why is this not working?
I am using the following libraries:

- flying-saucer-core-9.0.8.jar
- flying-saucer-pdf-9.0.8.jar
- itext-2.1.7.jar

Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: Any luck getting this resolved?

Comment: I also have same concern. Has this been resolved